# Subnet not appearing when creating AuroraDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I've created a VPC.  By default the VPC created one public and one private subnet.  I've created an additional private subnet in a different availability zone.

I then (in the ElasticCache console) created a new subnet group that contains these two private subnets from the VPC.  This subnet group is also associated, of course, with the VPC.

Then, on creating an Aurora RDS within this VPC, it asks for a subnet group.  There's one there, a 'default' group, but my new subnet group doesn't appear.

How do I create a subnet group that is acceptable when creating a database?

Comment: Hi ticktok, do you mind accepting the answer unless you need more clarification here?

Answer (score 1):

Well.. as it turns out the ElasticCache subnet groups are not visible when creating a database.  You have to use the RDS console to create a 'Database Subnet Group'.  Once you do that.. you're set.

Answer (score 1):

ElasticCache and RDS are different types of product groups. Their SubnetGroups are different entities and they don't over lap with each other. You would need to create subnet groups in RDS to use it with RDS engines (database engines). They are not tied to any db engine, so you can re-use them within RDS.

One additional thing to note is that some other Database productions like Amazon Neptune and Amazon DocDB are able to access your RDS subnet groups as well. Just an FYI.